# Connection 802.1x supplicant failed

Tags: wireless, internet

Before everything was working ok, but now I keep getting

```
802.1x supplicant failed
```

And no connection to network. I can reset it with

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

But I was wondering if there is a way to fix this problem permanently so that it doesn't happen any more.

Answer (score 13):

It might be because you installed some other network manager like `wicd` along with gnome-network-manager as this exactly was the problem in my case now assuming the same here is what I suggest:

1. Install NetworkManager:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install network-manager-gnome network-manager
   ```
2. Then remove WICD:

   ```
   sudo apt-get autoremove wicd wicd-gtk
   ```
3. Restart your system.
4. Confirm everything is working, then remove WICD config files:

   ```
   sudo dpkg --purge wicd wicd-gtk
   ```

Comment: I had `wicd` as well as gnome-network manager. But faced same problem. After removing `wicd` everything is working like charm.

Answer (score 5):

I had to install WICD because I haven't found the permanent solution for my Linux Mint 18.1 WiFi problem, even though I've made all the updates and every try suggested... so just using WICD or do:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Answer (score 0):

I confirm that in *Ubuntu 17.10* with kernel *4.13.0-45-generic* and *Gnome 3.26.2* I had the same problem after **wicd** installation.
After the PC went to sleep the Wi-Fi did not restore it's state when resuming.
So, I removed **wicd**.

There still must be some config to use **wicd** without this "...supplicant failed" error occuring.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the issue got resolved by running the command below:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Try these commands if the above did not work:

```
sudo service network-manager stop
sudo service network-manager start
reboot
```