# Ubuntu 18.04 Network Manager Hotspot crash on launch

Tags: 18.04, network-manager, hot-spot

[image: console log error]

Computer: HP ProOne 440 G4 4YW00ES
Wifi module: wn725n

Comment: `nmcli device wifi hotspot ssid test password abcd1234` pw requires 8 charecters

Comment: kos@kos:~$ nmcli device wifi hotspot ssid test password abcd1234
Ошибка: неверный «password»: «abcd1234» не является действительным ключом WEP (должен содержать 5 или 13 символов ASCII).

Comment: https://ee.hawaii.edu/~tep/EE160/Book/chap4/subsection2.1.1.1.html use the charecters from this link either 5 or 13 charecters..

Comment: `nmcli device wifi hotspot ssid test password abcde` should work

Comment: kos@kos$ nmcli device wifi hotspot ssid test password abcde
Ошибка: Не удалось активировать соединение: (11) Превышено время ожидания при проверке подлинности заявителя 802.1X.

but it doesnt work. Error the same. English version of error text - "802.1X supplicant took too long to authenticate." I try both variant: with 5 and 15 ascii chars.

Comment: related https://askubuntu.com/q/828076/739431

Comment: @PRATAP you are right, but as like this question, those question hadn,t answered yet.

Comment: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2168015 check this thread